# Where can I find the app's demo "Heroes" for angular + ngrx app?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm learning NgRx from https://ngrx.io/docs. They mention a lot about the app's demo (Heroes and Villains). Where can I find the source code to go through it?

Comment: This one? https://angular.io/tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: https://github.com/johnpapa/heroes-angular

and its demo: https://papa-heroes-angular.azurewebsites.net/

The best way of course is to recreate it on your own with all obstacles and issues.

Comment: thanks a lot, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Official [Angular](https://angular.io/tutorial) documentation has a [download link](https://angular.io/generated/zips/toh-pt6/toh-pt6.zip).